# HTML page with images using .net WebApi

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using .net WebApi to expose different endpoints with JSON data. Now I need that an specific endpoint returns HTMLs pages. I have implemented it like this.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("htmlPage/{htmlPageId}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetHtmlPage(string htmlPageId) {
    string rawHtml = m_logic.GetHtmlPageById(htmlPageId);
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage {Content = new StringContent(rawHtml)};
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    return response;
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is when that HTML page have some images. I don't know how to expose them because now I'm getting a 404 not found error when I call my endpoint from my browser. I have a folder in my project with these images and some Javascript scripts that I must return.

How can I do this?

EDIT:
This is part of my HTML

```
  <html lang=\"en\">
  <head>
    <title> Simplest HTML </title>
    <meta name=\"description\" content=\"The Html served\">
    <meta name=\"author\" content=\"acostela\">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./public/scripts/my-api.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> The first Simplest html served!!</h1>
    <img src="./public/img/success.jpg"/></br></br>
  </body>
</html>
```

My folder structure is the following

```
 -->Html
     |
     |
      ---> myFirstHtml.html
     |
     |
      ---> public
           |
           |
           ---> img
           |    |
           |    |
           |    ---> success.jpg
           |
           |
           ---> scripts
                |
                |
                ---> my-api.js
```

Comment: Don't use ./ but ~ as you can see in my example

Comment: @Ygalbel I tried your solution but I'm getting the same error. GET http://localhost:8888/endpoint/~img/success.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: With your structure it should be localhost:8888/public/img/sucess.jpg

Comment: I know what my problem is! I must add a fileServer middleware to my webApi. I will do it in the next days! Thank you very much for your help! @Ygalbel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it. I added a static file server middleware using owin+katana.

I changed my startup class using this

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder application)
    {
        //Other webApi configuration
            application.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
            {
                RequestPath = new PathString("/html/public"),
                FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@"../../../MyProject/html/public"),
            });
```

Now automatically all images scripts and files that are under public are served when my html page is requested via my webApi.

What does this code is to translate my http requests "/html/public" to my real file system path specified in PhysicalFileSystem.

Hope this help anybody.

Answer (score 0):

WebApi can serve static file.

So you just have to set the right link in your html file.

For example:

[image]

Your `<img>` will be like this:

`<img src="~/Content/img/email-icon.png" />`

Comment: This is not working. I'm getting same error. GET <URL> 404 (not found)

Comment: Which url you try to reach? Can you share part of html code?